# Hypersonic DB (HSQLDB) and schemas with "$" dollar signs

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

Anyone know of a way to get a schema with a dollar sign in Hypersonic?

This fails:

```
CREATE SCHEMA Z1RP065$ AUTHORIZATION DBA
```

as does Hibernate

```
@Table(schema = "Z1RP065$", name = "sims_prod_fam_desc")
```

This use to work, but since the upgrade, no joy...  I am using the latest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE SCHEMA "Z1RP065$" AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE TABLE "Z1RP065$".T(ID INT PRIMARY KEY)
SELECT * FROM  "Z1RP065$".T
```

Usage examples added above.

Update:

A new database property can be set with `sql.regular_types=false` to allow the dollar sign without double-quoting a name, and to allow the underscore character as the first character of unquoted object names. The SQL equivalent is SET SQL REGULAR NAMES FALSE. This feature is currently availabe in the Subversion repository and will be part of version 2.2.9.

Comment: That does create the schema.  I tried single quotes, but double is the way to go.  However, the next step is executing SQL.  It now fails:  user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.Z1RP065.  Notice the $ is missing.  SQL will not execute...

Comment: I know this is spinning out of control.  Maybe I should rename this post.  I am using Hibernate to do all this, so when I do an annotation:  @Table(schema = "Z1RP001$", name = "prod_info_mst")  I cannot add the double quotes so all the generated sql fails.  Hibernate tries to create the tables and fails.  I guess the post should be "Hypersonic DB with "$"".  This is actually a company wide problem as all our schemas use "$".

Comment: @markthegrea: have you tried escaping the quotes inside quotes, like `@Table(schema = "\"Z1RP001$\"" ...`? I haven't tried it myself, but might be worth a shot.